# popup alert window does not open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want that after the button click a alert window pops up. But when i click on the button nothing happens.
My Code:

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="tinymce/js/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            $("#divpopup").dialog({
                title: "abc",
                width: 430,
                height: 200,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Close:
                        function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                }
            });
        });
    })

</script>
```

```
<div id="divpopup" style="display:none">
    TEST
</div>

    <asp:Button Text="sent" ID="btnSave" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Try placing `../` before the `tinymce/`.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/12400/

Comment: Can you do a F12 on your keyboard and see what is the error on the developer console? That should help you find the cause and troubleshoot

Comment: when tried to replace it with ../ nothing happend.

Comment: There is no error when on the developer console

Comment: Have you tried opening it this way,
$( "#divpopup" ).dialog( "open" );

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the display property of div as block before converting it in dialog. Here is the code:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
         $("#divpopup").show();
            $("#divpopup").dialog({
                title: "abc",
                width: 430,
                height: 200,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Close:
                        function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                }
            });
        });
```